# Scala Play no application started when grabbing data sources from application.conf

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I am trying to read in data sources from my application.conf file, but every time I run my server, or try and run test cases, I am getting an error saying that there is no application started.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

Unit test that is trying to read a property from my `application.conf`

```
class DbConfigWebUnitTest extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite {

  implicit override lazy val app: FakeApplication = FakeApplication(
    additionalConfiguration = Map("db.test.url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/suredbitswebtest",
      "db.test.user" -> "postgres", "db.test.password" -> "postgres", "db.test.driver" -> "org.postgresql.Driver"))
  val dbManagementWeb = new DbManagementWeb with DbConfigWeb with DbTestQualifier
  "DbConfigWebTest" must {
    "have the same username as what is defined in application.conf" in {
      dbManagementWeb.username must be("postgres")
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my `DbConfigWeb`

```
import play.api.Play.current    
trait DbConfigWeb extends DbConfig { qualifier: DbQualifier =>

      val url: String = current.configuration.getString(qualifier + ".url").get
      val username: String = current.configuration.getString(qualifier + ".user").get
      val password: String = current.configuration.getString(qualifier + ".password").get
      val driver: String = current.configuration.getString(qualifier + ".driver").get
      override def database: DatabaseDef = JdbcBackend.Database.forURL(url, username, password, null, driver)
      override implicit val session = database createSession
    }

    trait DbQualifier {
      val qualifier: String
    }

    trait DbProductionQualifier extends DbQualifier {
      override val qualifier = "db.production"
    }

    trait DbTestQualifier extends DbQualifier {
      override val qualifier = "db.test"
    }
```

and lastly here is my stack trace:

```
[suredbits-web] $ last test:test
[debug] Forking tests - parallelism = false
[debug] Create a single-thread test executor
[debug] Runner for sbt.FrameworkWrapper produced 0 initial tasks for 0 tests.
[debug] Runner for org.scalatest.tools.Framework produced 2 initial tasks for 2 tests.
[debug]   Running TaskDef(com.suredbits.web.db.DbConfigWebUnitTest, sbt.ForkMain$SubclassFingerscan@48687c55, false, [SuiteSelector])
[error] Uncaught exception when running com.suredbits.web.db.DbConfigWebUnitTest: java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
sbt.ForkMain$ForkError: There is no started application
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:71)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:71)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at play.api.Play$.current(Play.scala:71)
    at com.suredbits.web.db.DbConfigWeb$class.$init$(DbConfigWebProduction.scala:14)
    at com.suredbits.web.db.DbConfigWebUnitTest$$anon$1.<init>(DbConfigWebUnitTest.scala:14)
    at com.suredbits.web.db.DbConfigWebUnitTest.<init>(DbConfigWebUnitTest.scala:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Framework$ScalaTestTask.execute(Framework.scala:641)
    at sbt.ForkMain$Run$2.call(ForkMain.java:294)
    at sbt.ForkMain$Run$2.call(ForkMain.java:284)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: How is `DbConfigWebTest` being used?

Comment: Added more information

Comment: It is generally being injected via self-type into another class that requires a data source.

Comment: It might not be the "right" way to tackle the problem, but making all those private vals `lazy val` might defer initialization till your app is running.

Comment: I tried doing this, no luck.

Comment: It's hard to help without more context. You cannot really use `current` statically because [it will just error](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.7/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Play.scala#L71) if there's no application. Try refactoring so that you pass an `play.api.Application` through your initialization code and use `app.configuration` instead of `current.configuration` (you could perhaps make the app implicit to reduce clutter.)

Comment: So is there documentatino any where for the server startup lifecycle? Obviously I need to be making these calls after the config file is loaded into memory, but how do I determine when it has been loaded?

Comment: @ChrisStewart The [plugin](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaPlugins) and [global](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaGlobal) docs might be some use.

Comment: @Mikesname I tried to simplify this, adding in a test case as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the key problem is that `val`s in Scala traits are initialized at construction time, which is prior to the test Play application being started (presumably its lifecycle is tied to each spec example.) You have a couple of workarounds:

- make everything in `DbConfigWeb` a `def` or perhaps a `lazy val`
- give `DbConfigWeb` an abstract `play.api.Application` field from which to extract the config values (rather than using `current`) and pass it explicitly (the fake application) to whatever `DbManagementWeb` is as a constructor parameter

Here's a simplified version, using the first approach (which works for me):

```
import play.api.Play.current

trait DbConfig

trait DbConfigWeb extends DbConfig {
  self: DbQualifier =>

  // Using defs instead of vals
  def url: String = current.configuration.getString(qualifier + ".url").get
  def username: String = current.configuration.getString(qualifier + ".user").get
  def password: String = current.configuration.getString(qualifier + ".password").get
  def driver: String = current.configuration.getString(qualifier + ".driver").get
}

trait DbQualifier {
  val qualifier: String
}

trait DbTestQualifier extends DbQualifier {
  override val qualifier = "db.test"
}
```

and the spec:

```
import controllers.{DbConfigWeb, DbTestQualifier}
import org.scalatestplus.play.{OneAppPerSuite, PlaySpec}
import play.api.test.FakeApplication

class DbConfigTest extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite {
  implicit override lazy val app: FakeApplication = FakeApplication(
    additionalConfiguration = Map("db.test.url" -> "jdbc:h2:mem:play",
      "db.test.user" -> "sa", "db.test.password" -> "", "db.test.driver" -> "org.h2.Driver"))
  val dbManagementWeb = new DbConfigWeb with DbTestQualifier
  "DbConfigWebTest" must {
    "have the same username as what is defined in application.conf" in {
      dbManagementWeb.username must be("sa")
    }
  }
}
```

Personally I prefer the second approach, which keeps the application state passed around explicitly rather than relying on `play.api.Play.current`, which you **cannot** rely on always being started.

You mentioned in the comments that `lazy val`s were not working for you but I can only conjecture that some chain of calls was forcing initialization: check again that this isn't the case.

Note also that order of initialization for `val`s can be complex and, while some might disagree, it's a pretty safe bet to stick to `def`s as trait members unless you're sure it's some expensive operation (in which case a lazy val might be an option.)